# Windows Phone 7 Title doesn't exist in Panorama control

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, panorama-control

I'm developing a Windows Phone 7 application and I'm trying to change the look of the Title element.

All over the internet they show code similar to this:

```
<controls:Panorama> 
    <controls:Panorama.Title> 
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margins="0,80,0,0"> 
            <Image Source="/myimage.png"/> 
            <TextBlock Text="my title"/> 
        </StackPanel> 
    </controls:Panorama.Title> 
</controls:Panorama>
```

But when I run it, it just comes up with these errors

> The property 'Title' does not exist on the type 'Grid' in the XML namespace 'clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls'.    c:\users\lukecou\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\PanoramaApp2\PanoramaApp2\Homepage.xaml  22  10  PanoramaApp2

and

> The attachable property 'Title' was not found in type 'Panorama'.  c:\users\lukecou\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\PanoramaApp2\PanoramaApp2\Homepage.xaml  22  10  PanoramaApp2

How come the Title element exists for everyone else and not for me?

How do I gain access to it?

Comment: Its noteworthy that the error says "The property 'Title' does not exist on the type __'Grid'__ " why Grid and not Panorama?  Might be a small error in updating error string resources by MS or is it a clue to something else wrong with your real Xaml?

Comment: You will need to post more of the pages xaml, the bit you posted works fine on it's own (as long as you change Margins to Margin). Please reduce the page to an empty panorama and then update the code in your post.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones Yup sadly that was the problem, it wasn't inside the `<controls:Panorama>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its noteworthy that the error says "The property 'Title' does not exist on the type **'Grid'** " why Grid and not Panorama? Its a clue to something else wrong with your real Xaml

Answer (score 0):

Use TitleTemplate instead

```
<controls:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,80,0,0"> 
    <Image Source="/myimage.png"/> 
    <TextBlock Text="my title"/> 
    </StackPanel> 
</DataTemplate>     
</controls:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
```

Comment: Using the template is overkill if you don't actually do any binding. The Title property is the right way to go here.

Comment: I found the problem in TS code: right `Margin="0,80,0,0"` not a `Margins="0,80,0,0"` . Please let me know if it still not work in your project